# How do I know from a BeagleBone Black if it is connected via USB (as a client/slave)?

Tags: linux, usb, hardware, embedded

BeagleBone Black has an USB port which allows the user to access it through ssh. In general, we could say that when you plug it to a PC, the PC is the USB host and the BBB is the USB client. On the other hand, it is also possible to turn the BBB on without the USB cable, through its AC cable.

I would like to know if it is possible to check, from the BBB point of view, if there is an USB cable plugged to the BBB or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsusb` command and it will show up kinda like this:

```
# lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 0a5c:2110 Broadcom Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 0000:0000
```